# IVR integration with billing

Tags: restcomm

Can you please enlighten on how billing server is to integrate with IVR? I mean when a call is terminated to IVR if it has to check billing/credit eligibility before transferring the call to an agent/terminating user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your billing server supports Diameter for real time billing, you can use [Restcomm jDiameter](https://github.com/RestComm/jdiameter) in your application to connect to your Billing System and have the IVR being notified if the user runs out of money and cut the call.

If your billing server supports HTTP then you can do the same thing via REST API calls to your Billing server without any additional software

Comment: Probably it is jDiameter, I think I am sure. What I tried to know, once a call is originated from a mobile device is it terminated in IVR or billing? If it is IVR then there should be some configuration for credit check response from billing. What is that configuration in IVR? If it is billing then how the call is handled? Definitely the billing will not have SIP protocol to handle voice call!! Please elaborate the full call process associating billing concept with your Restcomm IVR. Thanks

Comment: A tutorial like, http://docs.telestax.com/restcomm-building-a-car-repair-ivr-solution/  would help a lot. thanks.

Comment: IVR is responsible checking with the Billing system if a given user has enough credits, then start a timer to debit credits from the Billing system as more minutes are consumed. When the balance is exhausted, the IVR terminates the call. Very similar to https://github.com/RestComm/sip-servlets/wiki/DiameterRoRf